# Bidrectional many 2 many morph models in Laravel

Tags: laravel, orm, laravel-5, eloquent

I have 3-4 different models:

- People
- Cars
- Offices

So there are many2many relationships between all 3:

```
People <-> Cars
Cars <-> Offices
People <-> Offices
```

Is there a way I can define a single Pivot Table with double morph, having a MySQL table like this

```
- id
- target_id
- target_type
- source_id
- source_type
```

This way I could add any new model it comes into the picture.

Comment: I don't think this is doable using Laravel/Eloquent's normal stuff. I imagine you could probably extend and augment the `MorphToMany` class to add this kind of functionality in, though.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that this relationship could be made directly but i have an alternative.

you need a pivot table called "people_car_office":

```
- id 
- target_id
- target_type
- source_id
- source_type
```

*People* models:

```
public function cars(){
     return $this->belongsToMany('Cars', 'people_car_office', 'target_id', 'source_id')->wherePivot('source_type', '=', 'People')->wherePivot('target_type','=','Cars');
    }

public function offices(){
     return $this->belongsToMany('Offices', 'people_car_office', 'target_id', 'source_id')->wherePivot('source_type', '=', 'People')->wherePivot('target_type','=','Offices');
    }
```

and the *Cars* model:

```
public function people(){
     return $this->belongsToMany('People', 'people_car_office', 'target_id', 'source_id')->wherePivot('source_type', '=', 'Cars')->wherePivot('target_type','=','People');
    }

public function offices(){
     return $this->belongsToMany('Offices', 'people_car_office', 'target_id', 'source_id')->wherePivot('source_type', '=', 'Cars')->wherePivot('target_type','=','Offices');
    }
```

and the *Offices* model:

```
public function cars(){
     return $this->belongsToMany('Cars', 'people_car_office', 'target_id', 'source_id')->wherePivot('source_type', '=', 'Offices')->wherePivot('target_type','=','Cars');
    }

public function people(){
     return $this->belongsToMany('People', 'people_car_office', 'target_id', 'source_id')->wherePivot('source_type', '=', 'Offices')->wherePivot('target_type','=','People');
    }
```

this is how the many to many polymorphic relationship works.

----------------------- RESPONSE OF THE COMMENT -----------------------

when you wish to connect *People* with *Cars*:

```
$people->cars()->sync( array( 
     1 => array( 'source_type' => 'People', 'target_type' => 'Cars' ),
     2 => array( 'source_type' => 'People', 'target_type' => 'Cars' ),
     ...
));
```

Comment: Sounds credible. Practically you build polymorh relationship using each time 3 fields (depending on what you need). What happends when you conenct an instance of people with an instance of car. Will it create thow roes in the pivot table?

Comment: when you retrieve an instance of Cars from People ir retrives you an Object Cars with all the results of the relation between People and cars